# OCaml "macros" for switching between String and Bytes module

Tags: ocaml

On Ubuntu 14.04, the default OCaml install is 4.01.0. On my mac, it was 4.02.1. The Bytes module was introduced in 4.02 so I got compile errors initially trying to make my project on the linux box. What is the best way to check before compilation to use Bytes or String in a module.

Specifically, I was just using Bytes.create. This wasn't necessary. Right now I'd just like to know how to pick one or the other precompile-time.

Answer (score 4):

You can install the [ocaml-bytes](https://github.com/chambart/ocaml-bytes) library.

You can simply install it and it will either add a byte module similar to the one in 4.02 or install a dummy package.

You can also install [opam](http://opam.ocamlpro.com/) which will allow you to handle easily different versions of the compiler. The `base-bytes` package will behave quite the same as ocaml-bytes.

Answer (score 3):

For older compilers there is a `base-bytes` library that creates a compatibility layer for you. You can install it from opam with `opam install base-bytes`. If you do not have an access to `opam`, then you need to reimplement this library to some extent.